# Simplify this expression $e^{\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\psi\left(\frac12-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, digamma-function, polygamma

Is it possible to simplify this constant expression $e^{\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\psi\left(\frac12-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}$?

Here $\psi(x)$ is digamma function.

Particularly, the constant is real, so it would be good to get rid of the imaginary numbers here.

A similar question about the following:
$$e^{\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\psi\left(\frac12-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}$$

Comment: Why "simplify $e^\Xi$" instead of just "simplify $\Xi$"?

Comment: @metamorphy because this is the finite result I need.

Comment: @metamorphy if the sign was minus, the trick would work...

Comment: @metamorphy I don't see now can I reduce to one digamma...

Comment: Oh, I see $$e^{\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\psi\left(\frac12-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}=e^{\pi\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+2\psi\left(\frac12-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}$$

Comment: Nothing really nice. You can use series or integral representations for digamma, but I don't see any way to simplify this to elementary functions

Comment: There is a method to evaluate $\psi(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb Q$.  I wonder if it can be extended to certain finite extensions of $\mathbb Q$, such as $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-3}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one of these is "simpler"
$$
e^{\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\psi\left(\frac12-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}\\
=e^{2\operatorname{Re}\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}\\
=\left(e^{\operatorname{Re}\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}\right)^2\\
=\left|e^{\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}\right|^2\\
$$

Comment: Can this be similarly applied to $e^{\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\psi\left(\frac12-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}$?

Comment: No, this does not work for $1/2+1/(2\sqrt{3})$.  It does work for $a+ib$ where $a,b$ are real.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, there's no way to avoid using digamma functions here, however it's easy enough to show that this expression is real.

$$\psi(1+z)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+z} \right)$$

$$\psi(1/2+z)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1/2+z} \right)$$

$$\psi(1/2+z)+\psi(1/2-z)=-2\gamma+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1/2+z}-\frac{1}{n-1/2-z} \right)=$$

$$=-2\gamma+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{n-1/2}{(n-1/2)^2-z^2} \right)$$

So we have:

$$\color{blue}{\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)= \\ =-2\gamma+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{n-1/2}{(n-1/2)^2+1/12} \right)}$$

I believe Euler–Maclaurin formula could be useful in calculating this series to high precision, as the integral of the general term w.r.t. $n$ has an elementary form.

$\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant